# Matplotlib: Setting minor ticks in imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to get minor ticks enabled on an `imshow` plot with `matplotlib` but am out of luck.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
im = plt.imshow(np.random.random((3,3)))
im.axes.tick_params(axis='both',which='both',direction='out')
plt.show()
```

The above does not work. Using `plt.minorticks_on()` only turns on the minor ticks for the y-axis.

Comment: It works for me. I see minor ticks on both axes

Comment: Thanks for checking. What version of matplotlib are you using, if you don't mind me asking (`import matplotlib as mpl; print(mpl.__version__)`). I am running 3.1.3. I'll try upgrading.

Comment: python 3.6.8, matplotlib 2.2.3 on RHEL7. I can try newer one as well

Comment: Just got it working with the newest version. I don't think I changed anything at all, so perhaps it was an isolated incident. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with matplotlib v.3.1.3. Upgrading to 3.2.2 resolved the issue.